# Pass JSX to child, and have the child edit JSX props?

Tags: reactjs

How can `<MyList>` add prop `myListProp={true}` to `<SomeComponent1>`?

I want **`MyList`** to manage props, and **not** the class where this JSX is declared (theCurrentClass)

```
<div className='theCurrentClass'>
  <MyList>
   <SomeComponent1 />
   <OtherComponent2 />
   <WowComponent3 />
  </MyList>
</div>
```

Is `cloneElement` the only way?

I need to constantly update these props / styles, and don't want to continuously clone the JSX.

Comment: I really don't understand why you need this.

Comment: Because this class shouldn't be playing the role of the list. This class has nothing to do with telling an item that it's selected, or that it should have an offset. This class specifies which items are included in the list, and shouldn't care about the list to list item interaction

Comment: Why don't you just pass props from MyList to its children using the spread operator?  Build an object with whatever properties you want added to the child components and add them.  See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: @KenGregory becuase MyList can't actually communicate with SomeComponent1 !!!! other than altering the `ref` for `SomeComponent1` which is just a `<div>` and inline styles. normally with react, you interface through props and prop callbacks, but the framework doesn't actually work for embeds like this

Comment: I think your question is missing some important details and code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does seem to be accounted for, both with cloneElement and JSX.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

```
return this.props.children.map((child, index) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    ...child.props,
  });
});
```

---

```
return this.props.children.map((child, index) => {
  return ( <child.type {...child.props}></child.type> );
});
```

I can interface with the element by adding props the same way I do with any rendered element

---

> NOTE: requestAnimationFrame loops should only edit the ref (passed back from the child in a callback on didMount), and rarely update props unless you want to deal with all the React "smart" analysis bogging down the 60fps

Comment: Looks like you ended up passing props using the spread operator.  Cool.

Comment: @KenGregory the spread operator is cool for sure, you can clone all passthrough props then delete non-html/component-only props before applying them to dom element, which allows you to be minimally invasive. this answer is mostly about "cloning" the element in order to change the props

Comment: Could you explain more in detail? If I have like `<Parent><div><Child>` how can I transfer a prop that Parent has internally to Child?

Comment: `<Child theProp={theProp}>` or `React.cloneElement(child, { theProp: theProp })`